# Removing top border from html table cells

Tags: html, css

I am in the initial stages of building a site with a table that will feature on many of the pages. I have successfully styled the table as I would like with the exception of a gray border at the top of every cell. I just can't seem to get rid of it.

[The site is: [http://www.randysrides.com/1970-chevrolet-camaro/][1]](http://www.randysrides.com/1970-chevrolet-camaro/%5d%5b1%5d)

The HTML for the table is as follows:

```
<div class="spec_table">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Engine:</strong> Wagner LS-3 (603 hp)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Transmission:</strong> Bowler Tremec 5-speed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Exhaust:</strong> Flowmaster Super 44 Mufflers</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Ignition: </strong>Crane</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Radiator: </strong>Be Cool</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Rear End: </strong>GM 12-bolt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Suspension: </strong>AVCO/JME</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Brakes: </strong>Willwood</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Wheels: </strong>Billet Specialties</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Paint:</strong> BASF Waterborne “Grinch Green”</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Interior: </strong>Mark Millbrandt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Seats: </strong>Recaro</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Sound System: </strong>Alpine</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I then have the following CSS:

```
.spec_table {width: 100%; max-width: 350px; margin-top: -31px;}
.spec_table table {margin-left: 0px;border-collapse:collapse;border: 0;}
.spec_table tr {border-left: 2px solid rgba(38,201,255,1);}
.spec_table td {margin-left: -20px; font-size: .9em; line-height: 1.1em;}
```

I just can't seem to get rid of the light gray border at the top of every cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jared

Comment: You've tried `border-top:none;`? or set the border equal to the background color to not make it visible? It also does not seem like the problem is being caused by the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/kJW2U/

Comment: there is no top border at all, see here http://jsfiddle.net/uej9J/ Looks like the problem is somewhere else (in your actual code), not in the code you posted.

Comment: Your page is doing the "page not found", so there is no live example given either.

Comment: The only border I'm seeing is the blue one on the left.  I'm also seeing a 'page not found' message, but I can see the table if I click on the link for the camaro
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kDEAC

Comment: The link was formatted wrong so it was appending extra. I edited it to fix it, should link properly now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a style for border present in your style.css

```
.entry-content tr td { border-top: 1px solid #eee; padding: 6px 24px; }
```

You need to override this style

Add this in your CSS

```
.spec_table td {
margin-left: -20px;
font-size: .9em;
line-height: 1.1em;
border-top: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding the "border-top:" style with !important was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much to everyone for the input. I am guessing the style for class "entry-content" was from my Wordpress theme. This was my first post to StackOverflow, but I will definitely be back and try to contribute myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your website link shows where the top border is coming from

```
.entry-content tr td { border-top: 1px solid #eee; padding: 6px 24px; }
```

Remove or override this selector so that there is no top border.

This bit of CSS was not in your example code, so presumably it's something you werent expecting to be inherited by your table?

Also your link has some extra stuff at the end so wasn't working.. but I found the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your CSS

```
.entry-content tr:first-child td:first-child {
border-top: none;
}
```

This uses pseudo elements to target the first table tr, to the first table td to then have no border-top.